# Rails - custom helper repeating code with fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a custom helper in my application.rb file, which looks like:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def add_feature_field(feature_type, object_form_builder, actions_visible)
    object_form_builder.object.features.build
    fields = object_form_builder.fields_for :features do |features_builder|
      render :partial => "features/fixed_feature", :locals => {:feature => features_builder, :fixed_feature_type => feature_type, :form_actions_visible => actions_visible}
    end
 end
end
```

I am calling this helper from my view like so:

```
<%= add_feature_field("First Name", customer, false) %>
<%= add_feature_field("Last Name", customer, false) %>
<%= add_feature_field("Date of Birth", customer, false) %>
```

This is working pretty much as anticipated, except for one major hurdle: the second time the helper is called, it renders 2 fields instead of a single field, and the third time it renders 3 fields.

I assume that what is happening is that the fields_for loop in my helper is picking up the previously built objects, and also rendering those - can anyone suggest a way of preventing this?

EDIT: For clarity, as per the comments, this helper method is being used within the Customer form; the Features being created are nested attributes.

Comment: why are you assigning to the fields variable?

Comment: This helper is being called for nested attributes within a form.